# When I change the URL, this error pops up and the API is not called on the screen

Tags: reactjs

**Admin URL**
[image: admin URL]

**Monitoring URL**
[image: Monitoring URL]

**Error Message**
[image: Error Message]

Is it a matter of simply adding Access-Control-Request-Headers to the server?